# Struts 1 Losing Request Parameters after Failed Form Validation with Multipart/Form-Data Enctype

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I have a simple Struts form. It has a few text fields and a file field. The 
`enctype` is `multipart/form-data` on my form. I validate in the `actionform`'s 
validate method.  If the text fields are empty, I return errors that they 
are required. Along with the visible fields, I pass a few hidden fields that 
are needed as request params when the form is processed and returned to the 
JSP. The JSP needs these request `params`.

Everything works great when there are no validation errors as the request 
`params` get returned by using the `ActionRedirect` class in the action. But if 
there are errors returned, I lose the request `params`. (I am able to access 
them in the `actionform` validate method or in the action).

How can I make sure the request `params` are passed 
back upon validation error in `multipart` form? Is there any sort of workaround?

Action-mappings (slightly edited for obfuscation) below:

```
   <action
    path="/saveQuestion"
    type="blahblahblah.QuestionAction"
    parameter="save"
    name="QuestionForm"
    input="populateQuestion.do"
    scope="request"
    validate="true">
    <set-property property="cancellable" value="true"/>
    <forward name="success" path="viewSurvey.do" redirect="true"/>
  </action>
  <action
    path="populateQuestion"
    type="blahblahblah.QuestionAction"
    parameter="populateRequest"
    name="ItemForm"
    scope="request">
      <forward name="success" path=".editing.Question"/>
  </action>
```

And my JSP form line:

```
<html:form styleId="QuestionForm" action="/saveQuestion" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Comment: can you show us the important parts of your code? (for me that would be the related action-mappings in struts-config file)

Comment: Are those hidden fields also properties of the ActionForm?

Comment: Th0rndike I can't paste the code here, but I have the proper input, name, and forwarding. My struts-config.xml is fine... everything works except when I have the multipart/form-data and the validation fails. Horstmann - yes.

Comment: Are you implementing the reset() method in your form?

Comment: I don't believe so Claudio.

Comment: @eipark you don't pass params upon submit, thus your params are missed.

Comment: Roman - what exactly do you mean? All my form parameters are definitely passed to the action. I'm only having this issue when form validation fails.

Comment: I have encountered this problem before. I can't help you without knowing some things about your code. Starting by the action mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two options to solve this problem:

- Change the scope to session: This way the data will be stored in session and you won't lose any data.
- Implement the reset method of your validation:  This way, when the reset method is called in your validation, you can repopulate the data of the form.

I hope this helps somehow. I might have some other suggestions in my old code files, but i don't have access to them right now. If I have time I'll check them out later.

Comment: Are there any side-effects or other ramifications of changing the scope from request to session? And does this reset get called after the validation, but before my form values disappear? How am I actually supposed to repopulate the data of the form - it's either in the request or it's not right? If it's not in my request, I have no idea to discern in the code which IDs and other variables I wanted.

Comment: First question: you'll find the form in session and it's expected that the form is in session. If you use the same form multiple times it could cause problems(other than the normal problems that session creates, gotta watch it out). Second question: the reset method gets called before populating the form(before calling the setter methods of your beans)

Comment: For the reset solution, I don't quite follow how this can help me. The reset is called in the very beginning before the validate - how am I supposed to pass along some variable I need from the form to the action that I am redirected to after the failed validation when the form's values all turn to null in between these two steps? Are you saying use a bean that is common to the Action afterwards and set its variables from the reset so it is persisted somewhere besides the form (which would require changing my action code)?

Comment: That's exactly what i meant. However I realize that this is not a solution in your case, unless you use the same form for both actions.

Comment: Wouldn't this require some sort of singleton bean? I have no way of accessing any variables in my post-validation action from the reset.

Comment: It turns out using the reset method is not suggested - at least implicitly - by the Java Doc: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html#reset(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping, javax.servlet.ServletRequest). It looks like there is no elegant, real solution to this problem except hacky workarounds in my user interface (e.g. splitting up the forms).