# <html:file> upload file error , -argument type mismatch-

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts-1

In my jsp i have a `html:file` like this, and in the form i have the getter and setter. but when running i got

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.app.app.struts.forms.MyForm.setDocfile on bean class 'class com.app.app.struts.forms.MyForm'
    - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"
```

jsp:

```
<html:file property="docfile" styleId="docfile" size="45" ></html:file>
```

getting the error only when submitting the page and i'm not uploading anything. (the upload field is not a required filed .)

Answer (score 11):

It seems to be problem with the encoding, the struts form doesn't recognize the submit as a type of file, make sure to set the form's enctype attribute to `multipart/form-data` and method as `post`.

So you should have:

```
<html:form action="/somePath" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></html:form>
```

Be aware that this could mess up things with your validation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241354/struts-1-losing-request-parameters-after-failed-form-validation-with-multipart-f) thread for more.

Comment: after a lil search i saw _Use `multipart/form-data` whenever you have an <input type="file">_ so i think its not only in struts,

Comment: it should be <html:form enctype="multipart/form-data" ></html:form>. I'm sure it's a typo :)

Answer (score -1):

add this dependencies to your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```